# x11vnc: gdm3 creates a new x11 display after login

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, gdm, 18.04

I would like to be able to connect to my computer running Ubuntu 18.04 remotely via a VNC client. I am using `x11vnc` server-side.

Here is how I start my initial `x11vnc` session:

```
sudo x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.x11vnc/passwd -forever -bg -sshxdmsvc -rfbport 5900 -create -auth /run/user/123/gdm/Xauthority -display :0
```

I found the `-auth` argument by running the command

```
ps wwwaux | grep auth
```

This works properly: with that configuration, I do manage to connect to the vnc server over SSH, and that displays me my login screen managed by `gdm3`. However, whenever I do enter my password, the screen turns black. When I run the command `w`, I get:

```
USER     TTY   FROM    LOGIN@   IDLE    JCPU   PCPU   WHAT
skasch   :1    :1      10:13   ?xdm?   12.27s  0.00s  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-
```

And if I stop the x11vnc and restart it with the following configuration:

```
x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.x11vnc/passwd -forever -sshxdmsvc -rfbport 5900 -create -display :1
```

then I can correctly connect over SSH to my actual personal session.

---

However, it is inconvenient and impractical to have to run two different `x11vnc` daemons to login then connect to my personal session; is there a way to configure `x11vnc` or `gdm3` to allow me to create a single VNC daemon to both login and display my session? This was working properly with Ubuntu 16.04 (and I believe it's because it was relying on `lightdm`).

Comment: I've been searching for an answer to this for years without much luck. Right now I just end up running two x11vnc services (through systemd socket activation and using the -inetd flag, so they aren't running constantly), one for each display. This is also necessary because "-auth guess" doesn't seem to work, or maybe doesn't work with the inetd setup, and each display needs to get pointed at a different Xauthority file.

Answer (score 4):

My installation is CentOS 8.3, and I experienced the same issue with gdm3 starting a new x11 display.

My workaround is similar to other solutions that use a service that starts x11vnc. For example see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644886/vnc-server-with-gdm-login).

In my solution, only one instance of x11vnc is used. The result is that the client always connects to the same port. For my users - this was an advantage.

Whenever x11vnc is restarted, it connects to the 'current' display. That is, the display for the greeter, or for the active user session.

It uses loginctl to find the active x11 login.

It should be noted that the result is not perfect:

When logging in or when logging out back to the greeter, x11vnc is killed and restarted with the new display. Whidh means that the vnc client disconnects and has to be reconnected.

This is similar to other solutions.

Details are as follows:

In `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
After=multi-user.target display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/etc/x11vnc/start_x11vnc.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script in `/etc/x11vnc/start_x11vnc.sh` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

# list login sessions
sessions=$(loginctl --no-legend | awk '{print $1}')
for session_id in $sessions
do
    session_attributes=$(loginctl show-session $session_id)
    IFS=$'\n'
    for a in $session_attributes
    do
        declare $a
    done
    # look for the login session which is x11 and active
    if [ $Type = 'x11' ] && [ $Active = 'yes' ]
    then
        break
    fi
done

# Now we should have the variables for the active login session
pid=$( ps -C gnome-shell -o lsession,pid,user,args | awk -v session_id=$session_id -F' ' '$1 == session_id' | awk '{print $2}' )
display_id=$(cat /proc/${pid}/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | grep DISPLAY | cut -d= -f2)

ps -C x11vnc u > /dev/null
status=$?
if [ $status = 0 ]
then
    x11vnc_port=$(ss -tulpn4 | grep x11vnc | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | cut -d\: -f2)
else
    X11VNC_AVOID_WINDOWS=never
    x11vnc_port=$(/usr/bin/x11vnc -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -noxdamage -display $display_id -auth /run/user/$User/gdm/Xauthority -rfbauth /etc/vncpassw\
d -repeat -shared)
fi
```

Then, in `/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/x11vnc/kill_x11vnc_gdm.sh
```

And in `/etc/x11vnc/kill_x11vnc_gdm.sh`:

```
x11vnc_pid=$(ps -C x11vnc -F | grep 'display \:0.*gdm' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
echo killing ${x11vnc_pid}
kill ${x11vnc_pid}
```

Comment: `ps -C gnome-shell -o lsession,pid,user,args` is returning hyphen (`-`) as session id.

Comment: @JoyceBabu you are right. It seems that this depends on the specific OS. The above command worked for me in the past (it was on CentOS, I believe). I'm now using Ubuntu 20.04.4 and it does not. I don't have access to the same environment any more, but you might try this: `ps -e -o lsession,pid,user,args | grep ^[[:digit:]] | grep gnome-session-binary | awk -v session_id=$session_id -F' ' '$1 == session_id' | awk '{print $2}' `

Answer (score 1):

When you use GDM with Xorg, it creates a new session to each user. (:0, :1..).
I had to do this on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I created a script for the GDM login screen and a script that runs for every user login.
For GDM login script:

on `/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/start-vnc.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Start VNC
Exec=x11vnc_server
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

The script caled above (127 is the GDM user id):

on `/usr/local/bin/x11vnc_server`

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/user/127/gdm/Xauthority -forever
```

For every user login:

on `/etc/xdg/autostart/vnc-start-user.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Start VNC User
Exec=vnc_start_user
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

and...

on `/usr/local/bin/vnc_start_user`

```
#!/bin/bash

SCREEN=$(who |grep "(:.)" |grep $(whoami) |awk {'print $2'})

/usr/bin/x11vnc -display $SCREEN -forever
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that worked well for me. I had tried multiple services, etc. and then realized what you said about GDM creating a new session for each user which brought me here. I had to add a `sleep 3` call before starting x11vnc in the `/usr/local/bin/vnc_start_user` script to get it to work for me after logging in, but that is no big deal. Thanks for sharing your solution.